# How to set a class attribute a specified number of times in Python

Tags: python

Suppose we have a class `Node` which is initialized as follows:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None, prev_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node
        self.prev = prev_node
```

and we create an instance `head` as follows:

```
head = Node(data=4)
head.next = Node(data=5)
head.next.next = Node(data=6)
head.prev = Node(data=2)
```

I'd like to add another node to the doubly-linked list, which I could do by

```
head.next.next.next = Node(data=8)
```

However, instead of writing ".next" three times, I would like to use a method which takes as input the number of times to call ".next" - that is, something like `head.next_n_times(3) = Node(data=8)` which would have the same effect. How could I achieve this?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None, prev_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node
        self.prev = prev_node

    def next_n_times(self, n):
        next_node = self.next
        for i in range(n-1):
            next_node = next_node.next
        return next_node

head = Node(data=4)
head.next = Node(data=5)
head.next.next = Node(data=6)
head.prev = Node(data=2)
data = 5

head.next_n_times(3) = Node(data=8)
```

However, I get the error message

```
File "sorted_insert_scratch.py", line 19
    head.next_n_times(5) = Node(data=8)
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

It seems like the `next_n_times` method works as a 'getter', but not as a 'setter'. How can I make it work as a 'setter'?

Comment: Write a `set_next_n_times()` method that takes `n` and the value to assign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to implement the append method for the Node class. You can easily do so with recursion:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None, prev_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node
        self.prev = prev_node

    def append(self, node):
        if self.next:
            self.next.append(node)
        else:
            self.next = node
            self.next.prev = self
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the next_n_times method works as a 'getter', but not as a 'setter'. How can I make it work as a 'setter'?

What you get back is a `Node` object, and you want to set its `next` attribute:

```
head.next_n_times(3).next = Node(data=8)
```

To do what you want you have to change the syntax:

```
def append_at_next_n(self, n, node):
    next_node = self.next
    for i in range(n-1):
        next_node = next_node.next
    next_node.next = node
    return next_node
```

To make it work in your example:

```
head.append_at_next_n(3, Node(data=8))
```

Note that `head.next.next.next` is currently `None`, as you only set `head.next.next`, so the above will raise an exception unless you add another node first.

Expanding on this, however, you could make it kind of work with an actual property setter:

```
@property
def appender(self):
    return self

@appender.setter
def append_at_next_n(self, args):
    n, node = args
    next_node = self.next
    for i in range(n-1):
        next_node = next_node.next
    next_node.next = node
    return next_node

head.appender = (3, Node(2))
```

It doesn't help readability though.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the `n-1` to `n-2` in my implementation; that way it works without adding another node first.

Comment: hm, so now `head.append_at_next_n(3, node)` really assigns to `head.next.next` instead of `head.next.next.next`. That will be very confusing when you start using this.  Maybe what you really want is a LinkedList class with an `insert(n, value)` method? so you could do e.g. `l = LinkedList(); l.insert(0, 1); l.insert(1, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None, prev_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node
        self.prev = prev_node

    def next_n_times(self, n, value):
        next_node = self.next
        # loop to the penultimate Node
        for i in range(n-2):
            next_node = next_node.next
        # set that value to the value provided
        next_node.next = Node(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    head = Node(data=4)
    head.next = Node(data=5)
    head.next.next = Node(data=6)
    head.prev = Node(data=2)
    data = 5

    head.next_n_times(3, 8)
    # and to see if it worked...
    print head.next.next.next.data
```

Of course here were not checking if all the child nodes are present, so this will throw an error if head had only 1 child.